# refreshControl (pull to refresh) laggy?

Tags: ios, swift, pull-to-refresh

Why is my refresh control for my table view laggy? When it's normal, you can see the circle move around 360 degrees, but when it's not, it just freezes - the refresh works, but it's lagging. It's not laggy when I refresh it for x amount of times. But **when I leave the view controller (lets say A) and go to another one, then make a new A**, the refresh control lags. Here's my code for the refresh control:

```
// Class instance
private var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

And this is how I set it up:

```
// In viewDidLoad()
refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshGroups(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl // >= iOS 10.0
```

`refreshGroups` just gets data and calls `tableView.reloadData()`.

**EDIT**

[image: This is the working version]

[image: This is the freeze version]

**EDIT 2**

[image: This is a demo of what happens]

Comment: What happens when it lags? It just does not move at all or move slowly? Also, is it only about the refresh control? Or do you see some other elements in the page freeze as well?

Comment: The circle doesn't move at all - even though the refresh itself is working. No other elements in the page freeze. I"m using firebase to get the data, then updating the UI on the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this issue and heard from other people. The solution that helped me and them is to create a `UITableViewController` instance and assign your refresh control to it. Note: the table view controller is created programmatically and is there just for the refresh control.

Code may look like this:

Put these into global scope of class:

```
let tableViewController = UITableViewController()
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

And these to `viewDidLoad` or wherever you do the setup:

```
tableViewController.tableView = yourTableView // I assume you have a table view there.
tableViewController.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

All the rest should be as usual, handle refresh control as you would do it normally.

Hope it helps! Comment down if not.

Answer was **updated**.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. Check my edit? Maybe that will clarify things.

Comment: Sorry then. Btw adding video/gif would be great!

Comment: I added the gif, could you take a look at it?

Comment: @MichaelHsu is it a custom nav bar? please also check the constraints for table view in Storyboard